How to setup secret/password values in Secrets Manager using CDK/Cloudformation?
We are looking to configure our SecretsManager instances via Cloudformation/CDK.
Based on what we've read, SecretsManager recommends using their generate secrets function.
Unfortunately, we can't use the generate secrets function since some of these secrets are values that are generated from 3rd party services. Things like api keys etc.
We are hesitant to put secret values directly onto the CDK code as well, since this is considered bad practice.
What's the recommended approach/pattern for this?

I create the secret by hand and then hard-code the ARN into the CDK.  That way, no secret information is ever checked in, and there is no risk (read: certainty) that CDK will erase the secret.
I do the same with key-pairs for the same reason.

The standard approach is to provision the secrets with AWS CDK and then populate the values by hand after deployment.

Lets say we populate the secret values via web console after deployment. Would further updates on the stack where the Secrets are situated revert the secret values? Given that the CDK code of Secrets on the said stack is not updated.

@froi No, only an action that caused a "forced replacement" could cause that to happen. However, at work we tend to err on the side of caution and manually create these secrets and tag them extensively to tie them back to a project.

No, replacement is not the only scenario that can result in your value being overwritten - changing the value or the value generation options in the secrets in CDK would overwrite it as well.
